# groupboxes becomes inaccessible using TAB after clicking button

Tags: c#, winforms, groupbox

I have a form which has two groupboxes (& other controls as well, its the groupboxes that are creating problems), a 'SAVE' button which saves the form data into a database & a 'NEW FORM' button which resets the form (ex. `txtName.clear(); rbCash.checked = false`). The groupboxes have a couple of radio buttons & have tabindex's set.

Now, an user has to first click on the 'NEW FORM' button to activate the form. User can move through the controls using TAB. Then, the user clicks on the SAVE button to save the form.

Now, the user can move through the groupboxes using TAB only before he clicks the 'SAVE' button. After he clicks the 'SAVE' button & then the 'NEW FORM' button & tries to move through the controls using TAB everything receives focus except the groupboxes & the radiobuttons inside it.

any suggestions why am facing this problem??

oh.. one more thing. All the form controls (including the groupboxes) are inside a very big parent groupbox which gets disabled on clicking the 'SAVE' button & is enabled again when user clicks on 'NEW FORM' button. When the application starts the parent groupbox is disabled. Clicking the 'NEW FORM' button enables this parent groupbox & all the child elements within it to be enabled.

help please..

Comment: Please check the Tab order numbers once again........

Answer (score 0):

You have to be sure that the boxes have

```
TabStop = true
```

If you are programming in Visual Studio also the tool under View->TabOrder can be useful (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984423%28v=vs.71%29.aspx))